# Discord.py channel.history() returning memory address, not a string of the message content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a simple discord bot that pulls the first message from one channel and displays it on another channel. All functions of this bot work, except when I call the variable holding the history function, I get a memory address, rather than the embed content.

```
channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
msg = ctx.channel.history(limit=1, oldest_first=True)
em = discord.Embed(title='Ticket Closed', description=f"Ticket `{ctx.channel.name}` has been closed.\nReason: {args}\n\nOriginal Ticket: {msg.content}", color=0x2ecc71) #error at msg.content
await channel.send(embed=em)
```

And this is the output:
[Discord Output IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ7MG.png)

Comment: Well yes, that's what [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) say  `TextChannel.history` returns. You can flatten it and access the first element to get the `Message` you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried for loop and it works fine for me.

```
channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
msg = ctx.channel.history(limit=1, oldest_first=True)
for i in msg:
   em = discord.Embed(title='Ticket Closed', description=f"Ticket `{ctx.channel.name}` has been closed.\nReason: {args}\n\nOriginal Ticket: {i.content}", color=0x2ecc71) 
   await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: Which version of Python do you happen to be using?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).